# DROPZONE - Handling Session Timeout in AJAX request during fle upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to handle session timeout for `Dropzone` AJAX Fileupload Requests.I am checking the type of request through this `if` condition in `PHP`:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{    
  //Here checking if session is set or not
  // If session is not set, I am responsing with
   http_response_code(401);
}
```

JS File

```
  error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    console.log(jqXHR.status); //Here Recieving as error instead of 401
      if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
          window.location.href="<?php base_url() ?>login";
        } 
   },
```

But in the `Jquery AJAX's` `error` function, I am getting the status as `error` and not `401`. Is this `Dropzone's` doing? Is Dropzone returning the `error` text ?

Comment: Try header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");

Comment: Please check this link :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ,i think you are missing third parameter in ajax error function callback.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) : *: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete with an error.*

Simple Working Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#click-me').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php', //Your ajax call
                success: function (response) {
                $('#post').html(response.responseText);
            }
        });
     })

  });



    $( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {

            //This will be called whenever your Ajax request encounters any "401" error response

            if ( jqxhr.status== 401 ) {
                alert('401 Unauthorized');
            }
    });


</script>

 <a href='#' id='click-me'>FIRE AJAX</a>
```

Comment: Bro, I tried it ,still not getting the value. I am using Dropzone. During file upload using dropzone if session gets timeout I want to redirect.

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle @Abhinav